# Can i use a map server other than Google maps in a android App?

Tags: java, android, dictionary, wms

Suppose i have a custom map server like by Web Map Service (WMS) hosted some where. Can i use this as the map in my android app ? Or is using google maps the only option ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use any maps that you want.  There have been several apps that have used [Open Street Maps](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Android).